# How to use Django flash message in thread?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have a view that triggers a long execution time function, at the end of this function I need to notify the user via **flash message** of the execution result. The function is in a **thread**. This is my code...

```
from threading import Thread 
from django.contrib import messages

def long_time_view(request, pk):

    def thread_func():
         #stuff
        if success:
            messages.success(
                request,
                "Hurrah.",
            )
        else:
            messages.error(
                request,
                "Upss.",
            )
    messages.info(request, "Started Work.")
    thread = Thread(target=thread_func)
    thread.start()
    return redirect(request.GET.get("return_to", "/"))
```

#### The Problem

The message that notifies the user that the job has started is displayed but the results are not, even after the page is reloaded. So my question is how to show the results to the user from the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while but in case someone needs it, at some point, I solved this with a middleware

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it yourself. Do you have another example of your solution? Please provide it as well.